# Robot framework: Differences between suite setup and test setup?

Tags: automation, robotframework

I'm new to robot framework. Could any one explain to me the differences between **suite setup** and **test setup**? When to use? Examples...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the simplest terms possible, a suite setup runs exactly once at the start of a suite. A test setup runs at the start of a test case.

If you define a test setup in the settings section of the suite, it will run at the start of each test in the suite (ie: if you have 5 tests, it will run five times). If you define it in a specific test, it will only run for that test where it is defined.

A suite setup is a good place to do some initialization, such as starting a server, opening a browser, making a database connection, etc.

A test setup is a good place to do some work unique to the test that isn't actually part of the verification. For example, you might use the test setup to log in and navigate to the page being tested.

Comment: ahh...Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Test, is a set of operations performed to verify a feature.

Suite, Set of tests defined in same test file, testing the same feature.

Testing a feature means, you might have certain preconditions which may involve setting up environment for testing the feature. So these preconditions could of 2 types, one which can be performed once for entire Suite (all tests), others have to be performed before every test.

Suite Setup, as name implies it is a function (Set of operations) which needs to be performed before running a Suite.

Test Setup, as name implies it is a function (Set of operations) which needs to be performed before every test.

E.g.

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup   Setup feature environment
Test Setup    my Test Setup

*** Keyworods ***
Setup feature environment
    <set required environment variables>
    <copy required files and folders>
    <etc, etc .. >

my Test Setup
    <clean up or release previous test resources>
    <reset environment>
    <etc, etc .. >

*** Test Cases ***
First test
    < test steps>

Second test
    < test steps>

Third test
    < test steps>
```

So here, when you run the whole file (Suite), all the 3 tests will be executed.
The order in which they are executed is :

Setup feature environment --> my Test Setup --> First Test --> my Test Setup --> Second test --> my Test Setup --> Third test

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to specify a setup or a teardown for test cases in a test case file is using the :setting:`Test Setup` and :setting:`Test Teardown` settings in the Setting table.
Individual test cases can also have their own setup or teardown. They are defined with the :setting:`[Setup]` or :setting:`[Teardown]` settings in the test case table and they override possible :setting:`Test Setup` and :setting:`Test Teardown` settings. Having no keyword after a :setting:`[Setup]` or :setting:`[Teardown]` setting means having no setup or teardown. It is also possible to use value NONE to indicate that a test has no setup/teardown.

```
*** Settings ***

Test Setup       Open Application    App A

Test Teardown    Close Application


*** Test Cases ***

Default values

    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown from setting table

    Do Something


Overridden setup

    [Documentation]    Own setup, teardown from setting table

    [Setup]    Open Application    App B

    Do Something


No teardown

    [Documentation]    Default setup, no teardown at all

    Do Something

    [Teardown]


No teardown 2

    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown can be disabled also with special value NONE

    Do Something

    [Teardown]    NONE


Using variables

    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown specified using variables

    [Setup]    ${SETUP}

    Do Something

    [Teardown]    ${TEARDOWN}


Taking above example posted by Waman

    *** Settings ***
    Suite Setup   Setup feature environment
    Test Setup    my Test Setup
    
    *** Keyworods ***
    Setup feature environment
        <set required environment variables>
        <copy required files and folders>
        <etc, etc .. >
    
    my Test Setup
        <clean up or release previous test resources>
        <reset environment>
        <etc, etc .. >
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    First test
        < test steps>
    
    Second test
        [setup]  Testcase specific setup
        < test steps>
    
    Third test
        < test steps>
```

So here, when you run the whole file (Suite), all the 3 tests will be executed. The order in which they are executed is :

Setup feature environment --> my Test Setup --> First Test --> Testcase specific setup --> Second test --> my Test Setup --> Third test

The `[setup]` in second test case overrides the `[Test Setup]`. So 'my Test Setup' is not executed in second test case